# Slack API bot not recognizing bot event subscriptions

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I have a slack bot that, for some reason, stopped recognizing certain bot events. I am using the slackeventsapi to import the SlackEventAdapter, and using it to recognize certain bot events, like reaction_added and reaction_removed. Recently that stopped working altogether on my bot, I reset my bot and it still doesn't work. I am unsure as to why.

I have already checked my slack api bot event subscriptions, and I am subscribed to both those events, so I am unsure as to what exactly is causing this to happen. The bot can still post messages to the chat, it just doesn't recognize certain bot events.

Below is an example of some code I am trying to run. the /test works, the reaction_added event never gets called and nothing gets invoked and never prints the payload.

```py
import os

import slack_sdk
from flask import Flask, request, Response

from dotenv import load_dotenv  
from pathlib import Path
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

app = Flask(__name__)

slack_event_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(os.environ['SIGNING_SECRET'],'/slack/events', app)
client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    print("recognized a test command was sent!")
    return Response(), 200

@slack_event_adapter.on("reaction_added")
def reaction(payLoad) -> None:
    print(payLoad)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8088)
```

I am running everything on an ngrok server. to better clarify, when I use the /test command on the bot I get a HTTP request POST with return of 200. when I add a reaction to something I do not get an HTTP request, I am unsure as to why.

Comment: Hi @Eric, thanks for posting your first question mate.

Could you please share your code, and process flow so we know how to approach the answer? Many thanks!

Comment: @OliverKucharzewski sure thing! just edited the question to include the code.